# Git: how to remove the strange files that suddenly appeared in the staged/unstaged list in Rstudio

Tags: git, rstudio

I am working on a project in R Studio that has version control. After updating my computer to Windows 7, all of the sudden this enormous list of strange files appeared in the list of staged and unstaged files. Files like Microsoft.NET, Setup/, WMSysPr9.prx, and hundreds of other files.

I have no idea how those files got there, what they are, and most importantly: how to get rid of them.

One thing I did notice is that in the upper right corner it says "No branch", whereas I expected it to be a master branch, since I own the project. Could it have something to do with that?

I tried to run things like  `git rm *.exe`, but nothing seems to have happened.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If the files have the ending `*.prx`, you may add this pattern to your [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file:

```
*.prx
```

Then add and commit the file `.gitignore` itself. Now the strange files should disappear from staged / unstaged list.

Comment: `.gitignore` seemed like a logical option yes, but there are two problems. Firstly, there are hundreds of files with hundreds of different extensions, so it would take a lot of time to add them all to `.gitignore`. Secondly, I think a third of the files are staged, and I cannot unstage them (when I try to un-tick them in Rstudio, nothing happens). So if I commit the .gitignore file, I'm afraid I will also commit all those weird files..

Comment: you can commit the .gitignore only. However, you should try to find out what is the meaning of that files. Unfortunately I can't help, as I'm on Linux and have no plan about R Studio ..

Comment: I hacked my way around it by saving the R project on D:\ instead on My Documents on C:\, and adding version control to it again. This made the strange files disappear from the list of (un)staged files. However, it is still completely unclear to me why the files appeared in the first place, so any thoughts on that are most welcome.

Comment: If it doesn't matter it should be ok the re create the git repo. however, you could restore the old one and unstage the files. However, I have no idea why this happened

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows machine, RStudio defaults to C:\Windows\ when it can't find the project through Windows cmd. That's the folder all those "strange" files live in. Can occur if the folder name changes slightly, or the shortcut for a project gets a new target name that does not match the folder.

Comment: This is not an answer, user comments under questions to get more information about a question

Comment: This was the answer to a similar question I had about a bunch of random files appearing in what should ostensibly a be an empty repository. Although I suppose it doesn't provide much in the way of a solution.

Comment: My issue was with not being able to access a fileshare drive on Windows, which was solved perfectly by mapping the drive. As outlined in the answer to this question http://superuser.com/q/689227/508368

Comment: Yes, one solution is to check that all of your paths are in mapped directories. Windows .cmd cannot find UNC paths, so you need a lettered, mapped drive.  You also need to make sure that the folder path exactly matches the git one. Everyone I've set up to use git through RStudio on a networked Windows system has had some variety of this problem. It's always solved by mapping a drive and checking paths.